# date() function is not returning proper time

Tags: php, date

I am using `date()` function in the format `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. It shows `2013-11-22 06:26:25` when the actual time is `2013-11-22 11:56:25`.
My code,

```
echo    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

**date** function will display date according to timezone being set in **php.ini** configuration file on server.

So please set timezone on your server using **date_default_timezone()** function

For more details please refer the documentation mentioned in following url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Thankyou!  I got it right when i added the line,    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: if you have found the right answer so you should have accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

first set your time zone using this code

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

find utc code of your country here

> `http://www.date-default-timezone-set.com/`

then you can use

```
echo $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: please mark an answer as if your problem had solved.